# Firebase GeoFire: Is It Possible to Remove Multiple Keys at Once using geoFire.remove()?

Tags: javascript, firebase, geofire

The [current GeoFire literature](https://github.com/firebase/geofire-js/blob/master/docs/reference.md#geofireremovekey) talks about removing a single key but not multiple at once.

Is it possible to remove multiple keys at once using `geoFire.remove()`?

If yes, would the proper syntax for this action be `geoFire.remove('key1', 'key2', 'key3')`?

edit-1: x-post with [GeoFire on GitHub](https://github.com/firebase/geofire-js/issues/165)

edit-2: Both `geoFire.remove('key1', 'key2', 'key3')` and `geoFire.remove(['key1', 'key2', 'key3'])` methods return an error. So far it doesn't appears there is an option to remove keys in bulk via `geoFire.remove()`.

Answer (score 1):

Simply!

```
geoFire.update({ 'key1': null, 'key2': null, 'key3': null });
```

Answer (score 0):

The remove function only takes one argument/key. However you can take advantage of the `set` function like so...

```
geoFire.set({ 'key1': null, 'key2': null, 'key3': null });
```

This is similar to how the `remove` function works.